# Sorting set of string numbers in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, set

I need to sort a Set of String's which holds number.`Ex: [15, 13, 14, 11, 12, 3, 2, 1, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8]`. I need to sort it to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`. But when i use `Collections.sort(keyList);`  where keyList is Set, the reult i obtained is `[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. Please help.

Comment: String comparisons are alphabetic. Try to convert it to an Integer list to get the desired result.

Comment: Please post the actual code that you used.

Comment: Collections.sort accepts a Comparator as an argument. This enables you to define the compare function yourself. (Effectively, modify to int and then compare the values)

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom comparator and parse it as argument to `Collections.sort(Collection,Comparator)`. One solution is parsing your Strings to Integers.

```
    Collections.sort(keyList, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            Integer val1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
            Integer val2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            return val1.compareTo(val2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do as Kai said, and convert your String to integer and compare it

but it is expensive operation,what i suggest is this :

```
 keyList.sort(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1.length() == o2.length()){
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            return o1.length() - o2.length();
        }
    });
```

if your numbers has same length, then compare them by using `String.compareTo`, otherwise, sort them by order, so  1 2 3 will be automatically before 11 22 etc

Answer (score 0):

can you try with:

```
final int[] searchList =
        new int[] { 15, 13, 14, 11, 12, 3, 2, 1, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8 };
Arrays.sort(searchList);
```

The result is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The list needs to be `int`

Answer (score 0):

Transform the `String`s into `Integer`s first.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : strings)
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
Collections.sort(ints);
```

If you don't require duplicate values, you can use a `SortedSet`, which maintains the order automatically:

```
SortedSet<Integer> ints = new TreeSet<>();
for (String s : strings)
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
// all done!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Strings will be sorted as Strings in *natural order*, and not as numbers. So, `"11"` comes after `"10"` and `"2"` will come after `"11111111110"`.

What to do?.

Use `Integer.parseInt()` to parse each String value in the set as integer, then add them to a set and call `Collections.sort()`.